# Microsoft WPF Ribbon - Group buttons as drop down buttons

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have implemented the Microsoft WPF Ribbon in a WPF browser .NET application.
It is a pretty simply layout with tabs, groups and buttons in the groups. There are however a LOT of groups and buttons and users are having a tough time using the Ribbon on smaller displays. Some of the groups convert the buttons to small image buttons with no text which the users don't like. They have to hover over each button to see it's purpose.
Other groups collapse completely and change to drop down buttons. This they want as standard. Each group to be represented as a drop down button by default and when clicking on it a list of the items as menu items.

To get an idea of what I am after, you can simply reduce the window size until the groups collapse to this drop down effect with menu items.

Can someone help?

The buttons are bound to the ribbon dynamically as are the tabs and groups.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason the `RibbonMenuButton` doesn't suffice?

```
    <r:RibbonMenuButton
        Label="Clicking"
        SmallImageSource=".."
        LargeImageSource="..">
            <r:RibbonMenuItem 
                Header="Click Me 1"
                ImageSource=".."/>
            <r:RibbonMenuItem 
                Header="Click Me 2"
                ImageSource=".."/>
            <r:RibbonMenuItem 
                Header="Click Me 3"
                ImageSource=".."/>
            <r:RibbonMenuItem 
                Header="Click Me 4"
                ImageSource=".."/>
    </r:RibbonMenuButton>
```

Comment: I did not actually know you could nest buttons in buttons. This may work. Will try it out this evening.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might not be technical, but rather conceptual.

If you take a look at [Microsoft's guidelines on ribbons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx), you'll notice that ribbons are not necessarily the best choice if you have too many commands:

> **Is there a large number of commands? Would using a ribbon require more than seven core tabs? Would users constantly have to change tabs to perform common tasks?** If so, using toolbars (which don't require changing tabs) and palette windows (which may require changing tabs, but there can be several open at a time) might be a more efficient choice.

Maybe you should consider splitting your command groups on several tabs, grouping them logically so that actions that take place together often remain together, while actions that seldom take place together are on separate tabs. For example, changing page size and margins would remain together, while changing font size would go on a separate tab.

You can also consider using contextual tabs that will only appear under certain conditions, and therefore will only show commands related to what the user is doing at the moment.

Comment: Contextual tabs may be a good idea. The system has been in place for a little over a year now and used mainly by head office (Franchise). They are now rolling out to their franchisees and a lot of them work a 14" screens which is not working for this design.
HO like the way it looks but simply want the groups to change to drop down buttons. If you manually resize the browser window you get this effect. They want it permenantly though.

Answer (score 1):

You can control which buttons are displayed in a `RibbonBar` when they have been resized (internally by the bar). You can use the [RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbongroup.groupsizedefinitions.aspx) and [RibbonTab.GroupSizeReductionOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontab.groupsizereductionorder.aspx) properties to define how each `RibbonGroup` should be displayed. See this [Ribbon Layout and Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701790.aspx) page on MSDN for more information.